# Understanding how to turn Classes into Protocols in Swift

Tags: swift, inheritance, sprite-kit, protocols

My code works fine! But, the more I study about Abstract classes and Protocols the more I start to think that the "logic" behind my code is totally wrong. Let me explain you more detailed:

I have a `class` named `SpaceObject` which is a kind of abstraction for the inherited classes. It basically hold some properties and physics. **This class should not be initialized since it works just as "blueprint"**

```
class SpaceObject: SKSpriteNode {

    final var atmosphere: SKSpriteNode

    init(style: SKTexture, initialVelocity: CGVector) {
        atmosphere = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "atmosphere"), size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
        atmosphere.zPosition = 2

        // calls the initializer
        super.init(texture: style, color: .clear, size: style.size())

        physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: style.size().width)
        physicsBody?.velocity = initialVelocity
        physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        ...

        addChild(atmosphere)
    }

    final func cleanAtmosphere() {
        atmosphere.run( ... )
    }

}
```

Here I have the subclasses. They just "fill" the SpaceObject class but use its physics and some other functions (such as `cleanAtmosphere()`).

```
final class World: SpaceObject {

    enum WorldType: String {
         case Venus, Earth, ...
    }

    var type: WorldType
    var gravity: CGFloat

    init(world: WorldType, initialVelocity: CGVector, gravity: CGFloat) {
        self.type = world
        self.gravity = gravity

        // calls the initializer
        super.init(style: SKTexture(imageNamed: "world_\(self.type)"), initialVelocity: initialVelocity)
    }

    func touchedOccurred() {
        ...
        cleanAtmosphere()
        ...
    }

}
```

```
final class Star: SpaceObject {

    enum StarType: String {
         case Sirius, Polaris, ...
    }

    var type: StarType

    init(star: StarType, initialVelocity: CGVector) {
        self.type = star

        // calls the initializer
        super.init(style: SKTexture(imageNamed: "star_\(self.type)"), initialVelocity: initialVelocity)
    }

    func explode() {
        ...
    }

}
```

What I do for creating an object is just:

```
let newWorld = World(world: .Venus, initialVelocity: someVector, gravity: CGFloat(8.87))
```

and I'm sure it will have an atmosphere `SKSpriteNode` and some physics rules which are valid for each SpaceObject.

But... I'm not sure I'm doing it correctly, I read that protocols need to handle situations like this, but I still can't figure out how. Any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use inheritance to do what you want, but protocols are also an option. The advantages of protocols are that Swift structs can use them and a class can conform to multiple protocols but can inherit from only one class.

You mentioned physics rules. If you wanted to use a protocol, you would create a protocol for the rules and include the functions that classes/structs have to implement to conform to the protocol. That function would create the rule.

```
protocol PhysicsRules {
    // Add any arguments the function takes.    
    func yourPhysicsRule()

    // Add any other physics functions you want here.
}
```

Then your World and Star classes conform to the protocol and implement the `yourPhysicsRule` function.

```
final class World: SpaceObject, PhysicsRules {

   func yourPhysicsRule() {
        // Add the code to create the rule here.
    }

}
```

You could come up with better names for the protocol and the function, but this gives you an idea of what you have to do to transition to a protocol.

Doing a web search for `Swift protocols` provides many tutorials on protocol-oriented programming, including the following:

[A Beginner’s Guide to Protocols and Protocol Extensions in Swift](https://www.appcoda.com/protocols-in-swift/)

[Protocol-Oriented Programming Tutorial in Swift 5.1: Getting Started](https://www.raywenderlich.com/6742901-protocol-oriented-programming-tutorial-in-swift-5-1-getting-started)